# get IPv4 address into a variable

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

Is there an easy way in PowerShell 3.0 on Windows 7 to get the local computer's IPv4 address into a *variable*?

Answer (score 61):

Here is another solution:

```
$env:HostIP = (
    Get-NetIPConfiguration |
    Where-Object {
        $_.IPv4DefaultGateway -ne $null -and
        $_.NetAdapter.Status -ne "Disconnected"
    }
).IPv4Address.IPAddress
```

Comment: This works well, but it is slow, took 3981ms seconds to run on my laptop (i5-7th-gen/12GBRM)

Comment: This does *not* work on Windows 7 as the OP required.  The cmdlet was not introduced until Server 2012/Windows 8.

Comment: On windows 10 this was pretty snappy; only took about a second to run the first time (didn't really notice it) and after that just ran with no noticeable delay.  -- And it returns the correct IP address.  Nice work.

Comment: Get-NetIPConfiguration is not currently available in Powershell Core under Linux.

Comment: I get no output on Windows 10 PS 5, but splitting it like this it works: `$i=Get-NetIPConfiguration|Where-Object{$_.ipv4defaultgateway -ne $null};$i.IPv4Address.ipaddress`

Comment: `$i=Get-NetIPConfiguration|Where-Object{$_.ipv4defaultgateway -ne $null};$i.IPv4Address.ipaddress` Works for me in PS7 Windows 10

Answer (score 38):

How about this? (not my real IP Address!)

```
PS C:\> $ipV4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1  | Select IPV4Address

PS C:\> $ipV4

IPV4Address                                                  
-----------
192.0.2.0
```

Note that using localhost would just return and IP of 127.0.0.1

```
PS C:\> $ipV4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName localhost -Count 1  | Select IPV4Address

PS C:\> $ipV4

IPV4Address                                                             
-----------                                                  
127.0.0.1
```

The IP Address object has to be expanded out to get the address string

```
PS C:\> $ipV4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1  | Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address 

PS C:\> $ipV4

Address            : 556228818
AddressFamily      : InterNetwork
ScopeId            : 
IsIPv6Multicast    : False
IsIPv6LinkLocal    : False
IsIPv6SiteLocal    : False
IsIPv6Teredo       : False
IsIPv4MappedToIPv6 : False
IPAddressToString  : 192.0.2.0


PS C:\> $ipV4.IPAddressToString
192.0.2.0
```

Comment: There are IP Addresses specifically reserved for examples / documentation ( 192.0.2.0/24, 198.51.100.0/24,203.0.113.0/24) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737

Comment: `$ip = (Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString`

Comment: You can avoid calling an external utility with `(hostname)` by using the  `$env:COMPUTERNAME` environment variable, i.e. `Test-Connection $env:COMPUTERNAME -Count 1 | Select IPV4Address`.

Comment: This work well, thank you. To sum up all advice, THIS is the most elegant solution:

`$ipv4 = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:ComputerName -Count 1).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString`  I tested this on a system when connected to a wired network, and it shows that IPv4. When not connected to any network it shows home (127.0.0.1), and when connected to wireless it shows that IPv4.

Comment: How can I get the wifi ipv4 address? It shows my eth0 address which in my case is my wsl network down the road.

Comment: PWS 7.3.X slightly changed it to `echo (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Env:Computername -IPv4 -Count 1).Address.IPAddressToString`

Comment: This does not work with certain virtual machine software installed.  In particular, if VirtualBox is installed it returns the default IP of the VirtualBox Host-Only Network (192.168.56.1).

Answer (score 16):

Here are three methods using **windows powershell** and/or **powershell core**, listed from fastest to slowest.
You can assign it to a variable of your choosing.

---

Method 1: (this method is the fastest and works in both windows powershell and powershell core)

```
$ipAddress = (Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object {$_.AddressState -eq "Preferred" -and $_.ValidLifetime -lt "24:00:00"}).IPAddress
```

---

Method 2: (this method is as fast as method 1 but it does not work with powershell core)

```
$ipAddress = (Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1 | Select -ExpandProperty IPv4Address).IPAddressToString
```

---

Method 3: (although the slowest, it works on both windows powershell and powershell core)

```
$ipAddress = (Get-NetIPConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.IPv4DefaultGateway -ne $null -and $_.NetAdapter.status -ne "Disconnected"}).IPv4Address.IPAddress
```

Comment: This is not available on some systems:  Get-NetIPConfiguration

Answer (score 12):

If I use the machine name this works. But is kind of like a hack (because I am just picking the first value of ipv4 address that I get.)

```
$ipaddress=([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses('PasteMachineNameHere')|Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork"}   |  select-object IPAddressToString)[0].IPAddressToString
```

Note that you have to replace the value **PasteMachineNameHere** in the above expression

This works too

```
$localIpAddress=((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]
```

Comment: The second expression gave me the error below: `Program 'ipconfig.exe' failed to run: The directory name is invalidAt line:1 char:20 $localIpAddress=(( ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]
+                    ~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ $localIpAddress=(( ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed`

Answer (score 11):

Here is what I ended up using

```
$ipaddress = $(ipconfig | where {$_ -match 'IPv4.+\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' } | out-null; $Matches[1])
```

which breaks down as

- execute ipconfig command - get all the network interface information
- use powershell's where filter with a regular expression
- regular expression finds the line with "IPv4" and a set of 4 blocks each with 1-3  digits separated by periods, i.e. a v4 IP address
- disregard the output by piping it to null
- finally get the first matched group as defined by the brackets in the regular expression.
- catch that output in $ipaddress for later use.

Comment: ugly, but works well and way faster than accepted answer

Answer (score 10):

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.DHCPEnabled -ne $null -and $_.DefaultIPGateway -ne $null}).IPAddress
```

Comment: This worked.  Seems less elegant than the excepted answer though.

Comment: This is not correct. You may also need to include `DHCPEnabled=True`. The output of this command isn't the same as provided by @Lucas (`Get-NetIPConfiguration`).

Answer (score 5):

This one liner gives you the IP address:

```
(Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:computername -count 1).ipv4address.IPAddressToString
```

Include it in a Variable?

```
$IPV4=(Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:computername -count 1).ipv4address.IPAddressToString
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variant using `$env` environment variable to grab hostname:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:computername -count 1 | Select-Object IPV4Address
```

or if you just want the IP address returned without the property header

```
(Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:computername -count 1).IPV4Address.ipaddressTOstring
```

Comment: **BEWARE, THIS IS DANGEROUSLY WRONG**. It returns some IP address, but if you have virtual adapters (e.g. for VPN, Hyper-V, Docker, etc.), it may not be the one externally visible.

Comment: This definitely does not return the correct IP address on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

## tldr;

I used this command to get the ip address of my Ethernet network adapter into a variable called IP.

```sh
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %i  in ('netsh interface ip show config name^="Ethernet" ^| findstr "IP Address"') do set IP=%i
```

#### For those who are curious to know what all that means, read on

Most commands using `ipconfig` for example just print out all your IP addresses and I needed a specific one which in my case was for my Ethernet network adapter.

You can see your list of network adapters by using the `netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces` command. Most people need Wi-Fi or Ethernet.

You'll see a table like so in the output to the command prompt:

```sh
Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          75  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 15          25        1500  connected     Ethernet
 17        5000        1500  connected     vEthernet (Default Switch)
 32          15        1500  connected     vEthernet (DockerNAT)
```

In the name column you should find the network adapter you want (i.e. Ethernet, Wi-Fi etc.).

As mentioned, I was interested in `Ethernet` in my case.

To get the IP for that adapter we can use the netsh command:

`netsh interface ip show config name="Ethernet"`

This gives us this output:

```sh
Configuration for interface "Ethernet"
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    IP Address:                           169.252.27.59
    Subnet Prefix:                        169.252.0.0/16 (mask 255.255.0.0)
    InterfaceMetric:                      25
    DNS servers configured through DHCP:  None
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    WINS servers configured through DHCP: None
```

(I faked the actual IP number above for security reasons )

I can further specify which line I want using the `findstr` command in the ms-dos command prompt.
Here I want the line containing the string `IP Address`.

```
netsh interface ip show config name="Ethernet" | findstr "IP Address"
```

This gives the following output:

```sh
 IP Address:                           169.252.27.59
```

I can then use the `for` command that allows me to parse files (or multiline strings in this case) and split out the strings' contents based on a delimiter and the item number that I'm interested in.

Note that I am looking for the third item (tokens=3) and that I am using the space character and `:` as my delimiters (`delims=:` ).

```sh
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %i  in ('netsh interface ip show config name^="Ethernet" ^| findstr "IP Address"') do set IP=%i
```

Each value or token in the loop is printed off as the variable %i but I'm only interested in the third "token" or item (hence `tokens=3`). Note that I had to escape the `|` and `=` using a `^`

At the end of the `for` command you can specify a command to run with the content that is returned. In this case I am using `set` to assign the value to an environment variable called `IP`. If you want you could also just echo the value or what ever you like.

With that you get an environment variable with the IP Address of your preferred network adapter assigned to an environment variable. Pretty neat, huh?

If you have any ideas for improving please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing and figured this out:

```
$ip = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress
```

This filters out both the loopback address and some virtual networks I have.

Comment: Awesome, other solutions were returning HyperV/VMWare etc, but this one does just my WiFi adapter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ip = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile).InterfaceIndex).IPAddress
```

OR

```
function Get-LocalIP {
    (
        Get-NetIPAddress `
            -AddressFamily IPv4 `
            -InterfaceIndex $(
                Get-NetConnectionProfile
            ).InterfaceIndex
    ).IPAddress
}

$ip = Get-LocalIP
```

Comment: not sure about PS 3.0 (as per the question), but this does work nicely for 7.2.8... :)

Answer (score 0):

To grab the device's IPv4 addresses, and filter to only grab ones that match your scheme (i.e. Ignore and APIPA addresses or the LocalHost address). You could say to grab the address matching `192.168.200.*` for example.

```
$IPv4Addr = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily ipV4 | where {$_.IPAddress -like X.X.X.X} | Select IPAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Patrick Burwell's Ping Script - Patrick.Burwell@Infosys.com #
$Output= @() #sets an array
$names = Get-Content ".\input\ptd.pc_list.txt" #sets a list to use, like a DNS dump
foreach ($name in $names){ #sets the input by enumerating a text file to loop through and sets a variable to execute against 
  if ($IPV4 = Test-Connection -Delay 15 -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|select IPV4Address #run ping and sets only IPV4Address response variable
  ){# If true then run...
   $Output+= $Name,($IPV4.IPV4Address).IPAddressToString # Fills the array with the #true response
   Write-Host $Name',','Ping,'($IPV4.IPV4Address).IPAddressToString -ForegroundColor Green #Sets the output to receive the Name, result and IPV4Address and prints the reply to the console with specific colors
  }
  else{#If false then run...
    $Output+= "$name," #Fills the array with the #false response
    Write-Host "$Name," -ForegroundColor Red #Prints the reply to the console with specific colors 
  }
}

#$Output | Out-file ".\output\result.csv" #<-- use to export to a text file (Set path as needed)
#$Output | Export-CSV ".\output\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation #<-- use to export to a csv file (Set path as needed)

#If you choose, you can merely have the reply by the name and IP, and the Name and no IP by removing the Ping comments
```

Comment: Does ANYONE know how to get line 7 to write a SINGLE LINE into the array? :)

Comment: $Output+= $Name,',',($IPV4.IPV4Address).IPAddressToString # each entry goes into a separate line

Answer (score 0):

As I was working in Powershell 3, none of the answers here worked for me. It's based on Rob's approach, but this one works when you have multiple network adapters, it also picks out the IP correctly using capture groups

```
function GetIPConfig {      
    return ipconfig | select-string  ('(\s)+IPv4.+\s(?<IP>(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))(\s)*') -AllMatches | %{ $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups["IP"]} | %{ $_.Value }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non of the top comments are actually fully correct since a computer can have multiple interfaces and an interface can have multiple IP addresses. There are a few answers here which technically correct but utilizes "funky" ways to filter out wellknown addresses (like APIPA, localhost, etc) whereas even Powershell 3.0 have a native way to do so with PrefixOrigin.

```
$IPv4Addresses = $(Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object { $_.PrefixOrigin -ne "WellKnown" -and $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4" }).IPAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this :

```powershell
$interFaceAliasName="LAN" # You have to change the name according to your interface's name
$myInterface=(Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias $interFaceAliasName)
$myIP=$myInterface.IPv4Address
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me

> (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json').ip

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple method, split line with 'ipv4 address' on white space, and pick the last word.  It assumes 'ipv4 address' only appears once.

```
$ip = (-split (ipconfig | where { $_ -match 'ipv4 address' } ))[-1]
```

Trying this somewhat convoluted one made from two different scripts for network speed and renaming computers.  It excludes hyper-v and wi-fi.  Get-netadapter puts 'wi-fi' under 'name' and 'hyper-v' under 'interfaceDescription'.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapter | 
  where { $_.speed -and $_.macaddress -and 
  $_.name -notmatch 'wireless|wi-fi|bluetooth|802\.11|hyper-v' } |
  get-netipaddress | ? AddressFamily -eq IPv4 | % ipaddress

192.168.1.23
```

For troubleshooting, showing both the names and the ipaddresses.  You can check the netenabled property to see if an interface is connected too.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapter |
  where { $_.speed -and $_.macaddress -and $_.netenabled } | 
  select name, @{n='ipaddress';e={$_ | get-netipaddress -addressfamily ipv4}}, 
  netenabled

name                                        ipaddress      netenabled
----                                        ---------      ----------
Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection 172.18.136.171       True
Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter            172.25.96.1          True
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the same issue. So I wrote a script to parse it from the `ipconfig /all` output. This script is easily modifiable to obtain any of the parameters of the interfaces and it works on Windows 7 also.

1. Get output of IP config in `LineNumber | Line` format

`$ip_config = $(ipconfig /all | % {$_ -split "`r`n"} | Select-String -Pattern ".*" | select LineNumber, Line)`

2. Get list of interfaces (+ last line of `ipconfig` output) in `LineNumber | Line` format

`$interfaces = $($ip_config | where {$_.Line -notmatch '^\s*$'} | where {$_.Line -notmatch '^\s'}) + $($ip_config | Select -last 1)`

3. Filter through the interfaces list for the specific interface you want

`$LAN = $($interfaces | where {$_.Line -match 'Wireless Network Connection:$'})`

4. Get the start and end line numbers of chosen interface from output

`$i = $interfaces.IndexOf($LAN)`
`$start = $LAN.LineNumber`
`$end = $interfaces[$i+1].LineNumber`

5. Pick the lines from `start..end`

`$LAN = $ip_config | where {$_.LineNumber -in ($start..$end)}`

6. Get IP(v4) address field (returns null if no IPv4 address present)

`$LAN_IP = @($LAN | where {$_ -match 'IPv4.+:\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'})`
`$LAN_IP = &{If ($LAN_IP.Count -gt 0) {$Matches[1]} Else {$null}}`

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = ipconfig
$result = $a[8] -replace "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :",""
```

Also check which index of ipconfig has the IPv4 Address