# Powershell v5- Export only the value

Tags: powershell, scripting

How to export the below with only the value.

Currently it exports below like this: `PC IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.30.50.`

i would like the output to be: `PC 192.168.30.50`

script:

```
$ip = ipconfig | Select-String IPv4

$Host2 = Hostname

"$Host2 $ip" | Out-File "\\pc\c$\temp\Ipconfig.csv" -Append
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell get ipv4 address into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277701/powershell-get-ipv4-address-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$hostname = hostname
ipconfig | where {$_ -match 'IPv4.+\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' } >> $null
$ip=$Matches[1]
$Final_output = "$Hostname : $ip "
$Final_output
```

Comment: thanks that worked. I am new to powershell. Do you mind explaining how the following works
ipconfig | where {$_ -match 'IPv4.+\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' } >> $null
$ip=$Matches[1]

Comment: IPv4 matches the characters IPv4 literally (case sensitive)
.+ matches any character (except for line terminators)
+ Quantifier — Matches as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
1st Capturing Group (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
\d{1,3} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{1,3} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)

Comment: After the regex match, It will return all the ipv4 and all that I am redirecting to null.
 after that all the matched values will be stored in $matches
 so, $matches of 1 will give the second index value.